# "Editor placeholder in source file" Swift Compile Error in CAPBridge.swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, capacitor

I am creating an app with Ionic/Angular/Capacitor. My app has been compiling and building fine for a while. I was able to build and run the app on the Xcode simulation as well as my iPhone. However, I had a recent pop up for an Xcode update that I subconsciously click OK on without paying much attention about what I did. What a stupid thing to do!!! Now, I am getting a Capacitor Buildtime error of "Swift Compiler Error - Editor placeholder in source file - CAPBridge.swift in this area of the code:

```
public func modulePrint(_ plugin: CAPPlugin, _ items: Any...) {
    let output = items.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: " ")
    CAPLog.print("⚡️ ", plugin.pluginId ?? <#default value#>, "-", output)
  }
```

On the Xcode editor, the "<#default value#>” part of the code was replaced with a gray box and the “default value” text in it with the error message “Editor placeholder in source file”. I am not a Swift programmer and was not able to find any reason why this error would comes up now, or a way to fix it. I've posted the same question on the Capacitor Forum. However, I am hoping that someone would recognize the "<#default value#> syntax or know of any recent changes in Xcode that would cause such error.

There is one more observation. To make sure, I did a Clean before trying to run the app on the Xcode simulator again. When I do a Product -> Clean Build Folder, I got a different Swift Compiler Error after the Clean finished. I got "No such module 'Cordova'" in CAPBridge.swift.  This error will go away and be replaced by the "Editor placeholder in source file" error. BTW, I am using Capacitor and not Cordova and have never done a Clean in the past while things were all running fine. So, I am not sure if the "No such module 'Cordova'" error has always been there from a Clean operation.

The following is the output from running ionic info to show my current running environment:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.12.0 (/Users/francistse/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.25
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.25
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.2

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.2
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (1 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.2) : 0.15.1
   native-run                             : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.3 (/Users/francistse/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.5
   OS     : macOS Catalina
   Xcode  : Xcode 12.2 Build version 12B5025f
```

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve the compiler error by replacing `<#default value#>` with `"n/a"`.

Comment: Just to clarify, that can be whatever you want. The "n/a" will be printed if `plugin.pluginId` is nil.

Comment: Thanks, replacing <#default value#> with "n/a" did get rid of the error. However, now I got multiple "Editor placeholder in source file" errors in the Keyboard.m file. These were caused by <#code#>.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall @capacitor/ios and reinstall it to get the original code, then run sync

```
npm uninstall @capacitor/ios
npm install @capacitor/ios
npx cap sync ios
```

Comment: This worked. Reinstalling @capacitor seems to get me an updated v2.4.4. Seems like the code with <# #> in both the CAPLog.swift and Keyboard.m files are gone. Just FYI, now, I am getting 2 new warnings - "Coercion of implicitly unwrappable value of type 'String?' to 'Any' does not unwrap optional" on CAPBridge.swift and "Class 'CAPKeyboard' does not conform to protocol 'CAPBridgedPlugin'" on Keyboard.m. BTW, there are a few other warnings that I have investigated that do not appear to be problematic. Now, my app was build without errors and is running on my phone again. Thanks!!!